# Is there much overhead with AfxBeginThread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, concurrency

How much overhead is there when AfxBeginThread does it's thing?

I have an embarrassingly parallel project, and I want to launch batches of 4-15 threads with AfxBeginThread, wait for each to finish naturally, compare the results, then repeat zillions of times.

What has me concerned is that each worker thread is going to do much less than a second's worth of work, maybe 1/50th of a second or less, and frankly I don't know how many cycles go into the voodoo AfxBeginThread does to register the new thread, set it up, enter it and exit it naturally when the function ends.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

As a general principle, you probably want to avoid starting and stopping threads all the time. Create the worker threads *once*, and then feed them data zillions of times. Then you don't have to worry about the thread creation and destruction overhead (which is small but nontrivial).

Comment: This is pretty much what a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) does, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I am checking into the thread pool methodology!